# Python: How to move the position of an output variable using the split() method

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, split, partition

This is my first SO post, so go easy! I have a script that counts how many matches occur in a string named *postIdent* for the substring  *ff*. Based on this it then iterates over *postIdent* and extracts all of the data following it, like so:

```
substring = 'ff'
global occurences
occurences = postIdent.count(substring)

x = 0
    while x <= occurences:
        for i in postIdent.split("ff"):
            rawData = i
            required_Id = rawData[-8:]
            x += 1
```

To explain further, if we take the string "090fd0909a9090**ff**90493090434390**ff**90904210412419ghfsdfs9000**ff**", it is clear there are 3 instances of **ff**. I need to get the 8 preceding characters at every instance of the substring *ff*, so for the first instance this would be *909a9090*.
With the *rawData*, I essentially need to offset the variable *required_Id* by -1 when I get the data out of the split() method, as I am currently getting the last 8 characters of the current string, not the string I have just split. Another way of doing it could be to pass the current *required_Id* to the next iteration, but I've not been able to do this.

The split method gets everything **after** the matching string *ff*. 
Using the partition method can get me the data I need, but does not allow me to iterate over the string in the same way.

Comment: Welcome to SO, and nice job, by the way, providing all the info we need to answer your question!

Comment: Thanks very much Dan! I know some communities can be very patronising to newbies, nice to be welcomed this way.

Answer (score 3):

Get the last 8 digits of each split using a slice operation in a list-comprehension:

```
s = "090fd0909a9090ff90493090434390ff90904210412419ghfsdfs9000ff"

print([x[-8:] for x in s.split('ff') if x])
# ['909a9090', '90434390', 'sdfs9000']
```

Comment: could also do `if len(x) >=8`, depending on requirements.

Comment: shouldn't need to, try `python3 -c "[print('abc'[-8:end]) for end in range(0,3)]"` for out of bounds indices in action.  `print()` within a list comprehension needs to be a function and thus requires python 3+.

Comment: Thanks Austin, pault, and Dan Farrell. This works, however I am writing the variable "required_Id" to HTML, so passing "required_Id" as is returns a list of every single variable instance of "required_Id", not each variable sequentially. How would I write each item in the list one at a time?

Comment: better turn that in to a new question @AWSnell - we'll probably have to see example code.

Answer (score 0):

Not a difficult problem, but tricky for a beginner.

If you split the string on `'ff'` then you appear to want the eight characters at the end of every substring but the last. The last eight characters of string `s` can be obtained using `s[-8:]`. All but the last element of a sequence `x` can similarly be obtained with the expression `x[:-1]`.

Putting both those together, we get

```
subject = '090fd0909a9090ff90493090434390ff90904210412419ghfsdfs9000ff'
for x in subject.split('ff')[:-1]:
    print(x[-8:])
```

This should print

```
909a9090
90434390
sdfs9000
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Holden. I was already doing this in a different way, this gives me the same results as before. Thanks for the help though, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this with split myself, I'd use `str.find`.  This code isn't fancy but it's pretty easy to understand:

```
fullstr = "090fd0909a9090ff90493090434390ff90904210412419ghfsdfs9000ff"
search = "ff"
found = None # our next offset of
last = 0
l = 8
print(fullstr)
while True:
    found = fullstr.find(search, last)
    if found == -1:
      break
    preceeding = fullstr[found-l:found]
    print("At position {} found preceeding characters '{}' ".format(found,preceeding))
    last = found + len(search)
```

Overall I like Austin's answer more; it's a lot more elegant.

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. It's definitely easier to read yours, so thanks for being verbose, definitely helps me learn!